# 403 on file creation while using Hadoop.WebHDFSClient, Although was able to create Folders in HDFS

Tags: c#, hadoop, azure-hdinsight, webhdfs

This code works till the folder creation then could not create file and throws 403. am I missing some thing here for authentication. I am new to Hadoop and trying to learn hdInsight.

```
    private static void uploadFile()
    {
        //set variables
        string srcFileName = @"./prime/in/integers.txt";
        string destFolderName = @"/prime/in";
        string destFileName = @"integers.txt";
        string outputFolderName= @"/prime/out";
        //connect to hadoop cluster
        Uri myUri = new Uri("http://DXPZN72-LP:50070");
        string userName = "hadoop";
        WebHDFSClient myClient = new WebHDFSClient(myUri, userName);

        //drop destination directory (if exists)
        myClient.DeleteDirectory(destFolderName, true).Wait();

        //create destination directory
        myClient.CreateDirectory(destFolderName).Wait();

        //create outputFolderName directory
        myClient.CreateDirectory(outputFolderName).Wait();

        //load file to destination directory
        var res= myClient.CreateFile(srcFileName,  "/" +destFileName);
        res.Wait();
        //list file contents of destination directory
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Contents of " +destFolderName);

        myClient.GetDirectoryStatus(destFolderName).ContinueWith(
             ds => ds.Result.Files.ToList().ForEach(
             f => Console.WriteLine("t" +f.PathSuffix)
             ));

        //keep command window open until user presses enter
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was found to be a service needed restarted.Although I was able to create folders but was not able to create File with a 403.

I restarted my machine then tried again, the issue was gone and I was able to create file as well.